# The difference between 'can't stand doing' and 'can't stand to do'

Tags: phrase-usage

I see two sentences in my dictionary:

> 1. Lily **can't stand working** in an office.
> 2. She **can't stand to hear** them arguing.

It seems that both of usages are applicable. So, what will be the difference between the twos?

And can we say: "Lily **can't stand to work** in an office." and "She **can't stand hearing** them arguing." respectively?

Comment: The first set of sentences sounds better than the second. I can't tell you why, but I'd normally default to the *-ing* form, and use the infinitive after *can't stand* only if the *-ing* form would cause horror aequi (= two equal forms used consecutively).

Comment: I think it's regional. You certainly hear both.